# Antipode of Cocommutative Hopf Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry, hopf-algebras, group-schemes

I’m reading about affine group schemes by Waterhouse and in the proof of showing the (Jordan) decomposition of Abelian affine group scheme (equivalently cocommutative Hopf algebra), I came across the argument, saying:

“Since the Hopf algebra $A$ is cocommutative, the antipode $S$ is a coalgebra morphism and therefore sends $ A’ $ (a sub-bialgebra of $A$) into $A’$“

I know that the antipode is an algebra automorphism of $A$, and in this case a bialgebra automorphism of A, but I still don’t understand why does the restriction of $S$ to $A’$ would send $A’$ back to itself.

P/S: we are assuming that Hopf Algebras are commutative here.

Comment: It is not *per se* true that a sub-bialgebra of a commutative cocommutative Hopf algebra must be a sub-Hopf algebra. After all, submonoids of abelian groups aren't always subgroups. Maybe the context says something helpful here; perhaps finiteness conditions?

Comment: Yes, I should mention that $A’$ is a directed union of finite dimensional subcoalgebra of $A$. It was later shown that by construction $A’$ preserves multiplication and contains the unit - which makes it a bi-subalgebra.

Comment: That's not helpful. Try the "positive part" of the group ring of $\mathbb Z $; it satisfies all your conditions.

Comment: There is a given coalgebra projection $p : A \rightarrow A’$ that was also shown to be an algebra projection (and thus a bialgebra projection too). The only reasoning that I can now give is that for $a’ \in A’$, we have $p(S(a’)) = S(p(a’)) = S(a’)$, which shows that $S(A’) \subseteq A’$. But I still don’t see the logical connection that the author was trying to claim in the line he wrote.

Comment: but isn't that a valid proof, given this projection $p$ ?

Comment: Yea it is valid in that case. Guess he just left out the detail that I didn’t realise. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Is this projection written explicitly in the book ?

Comment: Yes it is. It was defined through the duals. For your reference the actual theorem proved was stated as: “every Abelian affine group (scheme) over a perfect field is a product of a multiplicative affine group and a unipotent affine group”.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have access to the book you are citing, but if i understand correctly, you are speaking about a commutative, cocommutative hopf algebra.
If your assumptions are complemented by: finite dimensional hopf algebra over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, then the author's claim:

> Since the Hopf algebra $A$ is cocommutative, the antipode $S$ is a coalgebra morphism and therefore sends $ A’ $ (a sub-bialgebra of $A$) into $A’$

seems to be correct.
Here is my argument:

Under these assumptions (i.e.: f.d., commutative, cocommutative over alg. closed field $k$ with $chark=0$), it is relatively easy to [show](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257846/about-the-classification-of-commutative-and-of-cocommutative-fin-dim-hopf-alg) that the hopf algebra $H$ is actually isomorphic to the group algebra of the group $G(H)$  formed by  its grouplike elements:
$$
H\cong kG(H)
$$
(This isomorphism can also be viewed as a direct consequence of the [Cartier-Konstant-Milnor-Moore](https://mathoverflow.net/q/259307/85967) theorem applied in the finite dimensional setting.)
Thus, by the same argument,  the sub-bialgebras $A'$ of $H$ -which are again f.d., commutative,  cocommutative, over an algebr. closed field of $chark=0$- are group algebras $A'=kN$, for some subgroup $N$ of $G(H)$. But then, since for any grouplike $S(g)=g^{-1}$ we get that:
$$
S(\sum_{g\in N}a_g g)=\sum_{g\in N}a_g S(g)= \sum_{g\in N}a_g g^{-1}\in kN
$$ 
thus $S(kN)\subseteq kN \ \ $ i.e.: $ \ S(A')\subseteq A'$.

Comment: Why are they group algebras $kN$?

Comment: By the same argument as in the initial case of $H$: The sub-bialgebras are again f.d., commutative, cocommutative hopf algebras and thus they are group algebras of some (sub)group.

Comment: Why are they Hopf?

Comment: because $S(g)=g^{-1}$ for all grouplikes.

Comment: @darij grinberg, i've edited hoping to become more clear.

Comment: No, sorry, it isn't any better. $H$ is Hopf, but why is the sub-bialgebra Hopf as well?

Comment: because any element of $A'=kN$ is of the form $\sum_{g\in N}a_g g$. And, as it is shown in my post $S(\sum_{g\in N}a_g g)\in kN$. Thus $S(A')\subseteq A'$. This makes the sub-bialgebra a hopf subalgebra.